# Structured data - Magento 2, 8 warnings

Tags: magento2, google, structured-data

I am using Magento 2, 
I used the structed data testing tools and all of my 600+ products have 8 warnings of which are some important ones such as image, availability, url

How do I correct this?

Some of the fields such as price, name etc are completed

Answer (score 1):

You can add below code in one file (catalog_product_view handler) and make adjustments accordingly. It will help to add all options of structured data. Hope this helps

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$summaryModel = $block->getReviewSummary();
$reviewCount = $summaryModel->getReviewsCount();
if (!$reviewCount) {
    $reviewCount = 0;
}
$ratingSummary = ($summaryModel->getRatingSummary()) ? $summaryModel->getRatingSummary() : 20;

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->escapeQuote($block->stripTags($_product->getName())); ?>" />
    <meta itemprop="image" content="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->stripTags($block->getImage($_product, 'product_base_image')->getImageUrl()); ?>" />
    <meta itemprop="description" content="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->stripTags($_product->getDescription()); ?>" />
    <meta itemprop="url" content="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->stripTags($_product->getProductUrl()); ?>" />
    <meta itemprop="sku" content="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->stripTags($_product->getSku()); ?>" />
    <div itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" itemscope itemprop="aggregateRating">
        <meta itemprop="worstRating" content="1" />
        <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />
        <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="<?php echo $ratingSummary / 20 ; ?>" />
        <meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="<?php echo $reviewCount; ?>" />
    </div>
    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php echo $block->getCurrencyCode() ?>" />
        <meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo $_product->getFinalPrice(); ?>" />
        <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
            <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />
        <?php else : ?>
            <link  itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/OutOfStock" />
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for that, where would this file be located in Magento 2?

Comment: this is my custom file.. you need to add this in catalog_product_view page as custom file.. This is not by default template file

Answer (score 0):

Actually the perfect way of doping this is to follow goolgle mark up structure:
Here it is:

```
<div>
  <div itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope>
    <meta itemprop="mpn" content="925872" />
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Executive Anvil" />
    <link itemprop="image" href="https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg" />
    <link itemprop="image" href="https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg" />
    <link itemprop="image" href="https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg" />
    <meta itemprop="description" content="Sleeker than ACME's Classic Anvil, the Executive Anvil is perfect for the business traveler looking for something to drop from a height." />
    <div itemprop="offers" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemscope>
      <link itemprop="url" href="https://example.com/anvil" />
      <meta itemprop="availability" content="https://schema.org/InStock" />
      <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
      <meta itemprop="itemCondition" content="https://schema.org/UsedCondition" />
      <meta itemprop="price" content="119.99" />
      <meta itemprop="priceValidUntil" content="2020-11-05" />
      <div itemprop="seller" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemscope>
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Executive Objects" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" itemscope>
      <meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="89" />
      <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.4" />
    </div>
    <div itemprop="review" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" itemscope>
      <div itemprop="author" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemscope>
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Fred Benson" />
      </div>
      <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating" itemscope>
        <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4" />
        <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <meta itemprop="sku" content="0446310786" />
    <div itemprop="brand" itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemscope>
      <meta itemprop="name" content="ACME" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can follow this: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

But for your site you have to place this code at specific place where need. Not whole code a needed snipet you can take from here and you have to put in your phtml file.